# Counting lines in polygon using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, count, direction

I want to determine how many lines go in which direction (north, east, west, south).

Is there a simple way to do that in ArcGIS Pro?

Unfortunately, I have too many lines to count them all by myself.

I tried to create a polygon with different sections for each direction (looks like a cake diagram) so I could count the lines in each section, but there are still to many to count by myself.

Is there a tool with which I can count the lines in the polygon?

The Polygon and lines I have now look like this:

[image: These are the lines and polygons I have right now]

I tried to make something like a wind rose. (The function wind rose report is not available for my version of ArcGIS). I am not even sure if that would have helped but it is no option for me.

The qualification for N,E,S or W would probably be the end of each line, since that is where the bird was heading. Although maybe I should calculate in more of one line but just the end point, since the bird did not always fly in a straight line.

Comment: I think your question would benefit from a picture showing a few sample lines, the polygon you created, and how you think those lines would qualify to be counted as N, S, E or W.

Comment: thank you! I will add that.

Comment: I would: 1 - find a way to generate the line end points, 2 - intersect the end points and your direction polygon, 3 - Summary statistics to get count per direction

Comment: That sounds good, thank you! What excactly do you mean by "generate the line end points"? Shall I create points out of lines, and then only use the end points? Or is there a simpler way? And how do I identify the end points out of all the many points?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Chit chat like greetings, statements of appreciation/thanks, etc should not be included in your posts here - see [help/behavior].